# Why isn't the chrome GWT css theme showing in my application

Tags: css, gwt

In my .gwt.xml file I have uncommented the following:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/>
```

When I run my application I do not see any stylesheet applied. Using Firefox there are a large number of warnings associated with Chrome.css. These mostly say that it doesn't recognize 'zoom' and 'cursor' so it is dropping the declaration. This seems to indicate that it is trying to use the theme but I see no evidence of it. The background remains white and the fonts seem to be the defaults.

Is there another step I need to take for stylesheets to be applied?

Answer (score 2):

Stupid mistake. I tried the dark theme which is more dramatic and discovered they were being applied. They Chrome and Standard just don't look like much on the standard widgets.